# How to run C++ files on the Google Cloud Functions?

Tags: c++, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-functions, gcloud

From what I am aware, Google Cloud Functions only allows you to deploy NodeJs or Python scripts.

**Question:** How would I be able to deploy a simple Hello_World.cpp on **Google Cloud Functions**? For example, writing a hello world HTTP function.

What are alternate methods to do this? I want to use serverless approach, since it's cheapest method. Therefore, that is why I'm going with Google Cloud Functions. Would I have to use docker in order to run C++ files? I've been stuck on this for a while and any guidance or help would be appreciated.

Comment: https://cloud.google.com/functions/docs/concepts/overview#functions : *"Cloud Functions can be written using Javascript (Node.js 6.14.0, Node.js 8.11.1) or Python (Python 3.7.0) runtimes on Google Cloud Platform."*.

Comment: @UnholySheep Yes I know.. :/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can't use C++ on Cloud Functions, period. You can only use Node.js 6.14, Node.js 8.11.1 (beta) and Python 3.7 (also beta).

If you wish to use C++ in GCP with a serverless approach, my best suggestion would be running your own [Custom Runtime](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/flexible/custom-runtimes/quickstart) in App Engine. You would still need to configure some instances options, but you don't have to manage servers and so on.

Comment: Hi @mangu. So this tutorial you linked for Custom Runtime, this will allow me to run c++ in GCP as a serverless approach. Thanks. Any further tips or pointers?

Comment: Sorry @tnet I'm not that experienced on C++, so, I don't know if you would face any caveats or issues with it. I have used CR with other languages. I suggest you use a Docker image in your Dockerfile that includes all the libraries you need, or almost all of them, to make this part easier. For example, [a gcc image](https://hub.docker.com/_/gcc/)

Comment: Maybe we can use Google Cloud Run which is the middle point between K8 and Docker. I know internally it's backed with K8 but google manages for you

Comment: There is a C++ Cloud Function API available:
https://cloud.google.com/cpp/docs/reference/functions/latest

Answer (score 9):

You can compile your C++ function into a WebAssembly module using emscripten. Then you can call it from a small nodejs glue code.

I built an example for you here:
https://github.com/ArthurSonzogni/gcloud-cpp-starter

Answer (score 6):

You can run C++ Code by node.js on google cloud functions (tested with node.js 10)

1. how to using C++ and N-API (node-addon-api) https://medium.com/@atulanand94/beginners-guide-to-writing-nodejs-addons-using-c-and-n-api-node-addon-api-9b3b718a9a7f
2. use https://console.cloud.google.com/functions and click CREATE FUNCTION to upload .zip or gcloud functions deploy  --runtime nodejs10 --trigger-http

> The trick is when you zip file you need to remove /build and /node_modules folder then use command line by cd to folder of index.js and 'zip your_name.zip -r *'

ps. when I use firebase deploy --only functions it will error because it doesn't know file addon.node format (in fact it shouldn't read this file because it need to be recompiled) but I think if we using gcloud functions command line with .gcloudignore for /build and /node_modules it will success https://cloud.google.com/functions/docs/deploying/filesystem

**HOW DOES IT WORK**

I think when you deploy node.js source code to cloud functions it will run npm install and your C++ code will be compiled too (like npm run build will be auto run after npm install)

Comment: This is the best answer. It uses gyp and n-api as part of the node build process. Works just fine for C/C++ in GCF.

Answer (score 2):

You can only use App Engine Flexible Environment (or, of course, standard VM architecture, Compute Engine). Extract from the docs (https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/flexible/):

```
Runtimes - The flexible environment includes native support for Java 8 
(with no web-serving framework), Eclipse Jetty 9, Python 2.7 and Python 3.6,
 Node.js, Ruby, PHP, .NET core, and Go. Developers can customize these 
runtimes or provide their own runtime by supplying a custom Docker image 
or Dockerfile from the open source community.
```

As an interesting side note, Google Serverless Containers will give you the chance to deploy your dockerized application but in a serverless flavour (in fact it's built on top of Google Cloud Functions technology). It's currently in Alpha stage.

Comment: Hi, regarding the alpha stage. Do you have information on that? I would like to use the alpha stage, serverless flavor. So I would like to implement and run a docker container that contains my static binary file (c++), for example, hello world.

Comment: You can sign for an early access here: https://services.google.com/fb/forms/serverlesscontainers/

Comment: Thanks, I applied for it so we will see how long it takes. Regarding what you said earlier, only can be done in ApP Engine/VM, which I already have tried. The only issue here is, it means I have to manage the server and also the costs. I would like to implement google functions only. If you know anything that regards, let me know. Thank You.

Comment: To the best of my knowledge, serverless containers will be the way to go.

Comment: I have signed up but in the meantime, is there much I can do? Since serverless containers is the way to go, don't I have to wait for Google to allow me to access it? I signed up for it but haven't gotten any email yet.

Comment: Update:
To deploy a function in google functions, following the HTTP example (https://cloud.google.com/functions/docs/tutorials/http#functions_helloworld_get_tutorial-python), it would be this:

"gcloud functions deploy hello_get --runtime python37 --trigger-http".

However, how would be do a gcloud function deploy for executing Dockerfile + static binary (C++ file)?

Thanks.

Comment: I suppose that you should not do anything other than create your dockerfile that makes what you need. What changes with serverless container is that google handles it as a cloud function (spawning only when needed and billing the time the function runs only).

Comment: I have the Dockerfile created but my issue is, how do I deploy it to google function?

Comment: No, you can't do it on google cloud _functions_, this is possible with google _serverless containers_, which is the service in alpha stage.

Comment: Correct, I mis-wrote. So what I'm trying to say is, I can't really do anything until Google allows access to use service for alpha stage? There is also "gcloud alpha functions deploy" but I don't think that has to do with anything here correct? Last night I was able to send my Docker image from my local machine onto the cloud and have it executed on the cloud, but this was via Cloud Build..(Which I really don't want).